# Why are several executions of an eventhandler triggered from the same thread if I am invoking the event from a different thread each time?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events

In order to learn the basics about Events in .NET, I made a console application that models a row of 5 domino tokens that fall when the first token is pushed with your finger. The interaction between each pair of contiguous tokens is handled by the event Fall in the current token and the event handler Collided in the next one. When a token falls, it invokes a Fall event to which the next token is subscribed by the delegate Collided. Each token takes 1000 ms to fall.

The first version of the program, running in a single thread, takes 5000 ms to complete as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace SimpleRubeGoldbergMachine
{
    public class Finger { }

    public class DominoToken
    {
        public event EventHandler Fall;

        public void KickOff()
        {
            //Collides with your finger and kicks off the chain reaction
            this.Collided(new Finger(), EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public void Collided(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var objectType = sender.GetType().Name;
            Console.WriteLine($"A {objectType} has bumped into the domino token.");
            Console.WriteLine("The token falls!");

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            //On falling, the domino token collides with the next token
            this.OnFalling(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void OnFalling(EventArgs e)
        {
            Fall?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rowOfDominoes = new[]
            {
                new DominoToken(),
                new DominoToken(),
                new DominoToken(),
                new DominoToken(),
                new DominoToken()
            };

            //Attach the Collided delegate of each domino Token to the Fall event of the previous Token
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                rowOfDominoes[0].Fall += rowOfDominoes[i + 1].Collided;
            }

            //Kick-off
            rowOfDominoes[0].KickOff();
        }
    }
}
```

Console ouput:

```
A Finger has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
```

My problem arises when I try to run each event handler in a different thread. Note that the reason for using different threads is that I am trying to kick-off several rows of dominoes from a single event that can run (i.e. fall) in parallel, but this part of the code is not necessary to reproduce my problem.

I start a new thread from within the Collided event handler for each token. To my surprise, the program **takes only 2000 ms to finish. I was expecting each execution of the event handler to be spawned from a different thread, but instead all of them are being spawned from the same thread**. For this reason, several Fall events are happening at once (which is not the desired behaviour).

I added traces with the ID of the spawner thread and the current thread for each execution of Collided() so as to troubleshoot the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace SimpleRubeGoldbergMachine
{

    public class Finger { }

    public class DominoToken
    {
        public event EventHandler<int> Fall;

        public void KickOff()
        {
            //Collides with your finger and kicks off the chain reaction
            this.Collided(new Finger(), Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        public void Collided(object sender, int threadId)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var objectType = sender.GetType().Name;
                Console.WriteLine($"A {objectType} has bumped into the domino token.");
                Console.WriteLine("The token falls!");

                Console.WriteLine("Spawner Thread: " + threadId);
                Console.WriteLine("Current Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                //On falling, the domino token collides with the next token
                this.OnFalling(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            });

            thread.IsBackground = false;
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void OnFalling(int threadId)
        {
            Fall?.Invoke(this, threadId);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rowOfDominoes = new[]
            {
                new DominoToken(),
                new DominoToken(),
                new DominoToken(),
                new DominoToken(),
                new DominoToken()
            };

            //Attach the Collided delegate of each domino Token to the Fall event of the previous Token
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                rowOfDominoes[0].Fall += rowOfDominoes[i + 1].Collided;
            }

            //Kick-off
            rowOfDominoes[0].KickOff();
        }
    }
}
```

Expected console ouput:

```
A Finger has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
Spawner Thread: 1
Current Thread: 2
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
Spawner Thread: 2
Current Thread: 3
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
Spawner Thread: 3
Current Thread: 4
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
Spawner Thread: 4
Current Thread: 5
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
Spawner Thread: 5
Current Thread: 6
```

Actual console output:

```
A Finger has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
Spawner Thread: 1
Current Thread: 5
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
Spawner Thread: 5
Current Thread: 6
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
Spawner Thread: 5
Current Thread: 9
A DominoToken has bumped into the domino token.
The token falls!
Spawner Thread: 5
Current Thread: 8
Spawner Thread: 5
Current Thread: 7
```

Why are several delegates of different instances of DominoToken being spawned from the same thread (5)? The spawning thread actually differs between the first interaction (finger-1st token, #1) and the second interaction (2nd token-3rd token, thread #5)

Comment: I think that there is a bug in this line: `rowOfDominoes[0].Fall += rowOfDominoes[i + 1].Collided;` You are attaching multiple handlers to the event of the same domino token.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias is right - all four other dominoes are handling the event from the same Domino.  You have one Domino colliding with the other four at once.  If you want them to collide one at a time, replace rowOfDominoes[0] with rowOfDominoes[i] when adding the event handlers.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias and Sean Skelly, thanks for pointing out my silly mistake. It works now.

Comment: Now you have to figure out why the first version of the program (the single threaded), although buggy worked as expected. Btw sorry for the downvote. You put a lot of work on this question. So you have a (virtual) +1 by me for the effort. :-)

Comment: No worries, I understand it. I can't debug it right now, but as far as I know, multiple event handlers attached to a single event are executed sequentially, so it's the expected behaviour that Collide is executed 5 times one after the other. Because each execution of the Collide event handler produces exactly the same output, regardless of the dominoToken instance, I didn't realise they were all executions from the same instance. Although it _actually_ wasn't the expected behaviour, it _looked like_ it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not work as expected because the attachment of the event handlers is not right. As pointed out by Theodor Zoulias and Sean Skelly in [their comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435867/why-are-several-executions-of-an-eventhandler-triggered-from-the-same-thread-if?noredirect=1#comment108679106_61435867):

> there is a bug in this line: rowOfDominoes[0].Fall += rowOfDominoes[i + 1].Collided; You are attaching multiple handlers to the event of the same domino token.
>
> You have one Domino colliding with the other four at once. If you want them to collide one at a time, replace rowOfDominoes[0] with rowOfDominoes[i] when adding the event handlers.

With this fix, it works as expected.